# Scrollbar in onTop side menu

Tags: codenameone

I think scrollBar should overlap the commands and components in side menu. But it leaves a gap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The scrollbar should be hidden based on the value of `sideMenuScrollVisibleBool` which defaults to false. Are you sending a versioned build? I think this only went in post 3.8.